# Solving a first order PDE system

Tags: differential-equations

How can I solve using Mathematica the simple 1st order PDE system:

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=f(x,y,z)$

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=g(x,y,z)$

$\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}=h(x,y,z)$

I want the complete expression for the scalar function P.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful -- You might also want to put your TeX between dollar signs.

Comment: @MichaelE2  That depends on whether the subscripts on `f` represent derivatives.  If not, then additional relationships are required for the equations to have any solution at all, as I am sure you know.

Comment: the subscripts do not indicate differentiation. I ve changed the notation so as to avoid this confusion. The functions f,g,h are given by very large expressions so I would like to solve it using Mathematica rather by hand. Actually It's not possible to manipulate the system by hand...

Comment: and f,g and h are components of a vector field

Comment: @DK13 How and whether the system can be integrated depends on the functions themselves.  `DSolve` will tell you the answer, if it can.  Did you try that?

Comment: DSolve returns just the input !!

Comment: That means `DSolve` can't solve it.  Is the curl of the field zero?

Answer (score 3):

In order for the set of equations in the question to have a solution, the vector must be `Curl`-free.  In other words, all components of

```
Curl[{f[x, y, z], g[x, y, z], h[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]
(* {-Derivative[0, 0, 1][g][x, y, z] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][h][x, y, z], 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, z] - Derivative[1, 0, 0][h][x, y, z], 
    -Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, z] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][g][x, y, z]} *))
```

must equate to zero.

**Example**

For instance, if the vector is given by the gradient of v,

```
vec = Grad[v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]  
(* {Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][x, y, z], 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][v][x, y, z], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][x, y, z]} *)
```

Then, of course, the curl vanishes

```
Curl[vec, {x, y, z}]
(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

and `DSolve` can provide an answer.

```
DSolve[{D[P[x, y, z], x] == vec[[1]], D[P[x, y, z], y] == vec[[2]], 
        D[P[x, y, z], z] == vec[[3]]}, P[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
(* {{P[x, y, z] -> C[1] + v[x, y, z]}} *)
```

as expected.  In contrast, if `vec` is not the gradient of a scalar, there is no solution, and `DSolve` returns unevaluated.  Unfortunately, the converse is not necessarily true.  If `DSolve` returns unevaluated, it is possible that it merely was unable to recognize that `vec` is the gradient of a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I tried it... The Curl of {f,g,h} does not vanish...

Comment: So I suppose that I have to modify, the components f,g,h so as to represent an Curl-free field... If the physical model permitts such a modification!

Comment: @DK13  Also, remember to run `Simplify` and, if necessary and not too slow, `FullSimplify` to be sure the vector is not curl-free.  In my all too  lengthy experience as a physicist, I have observed that most vectors in fundamental theories are either curl-free or divergence-free.