# Find Solution to Exact ODE with 4 Variables?

Tags: differential-equations, vector-calculus

OK, I give up. I was trying to use the solution in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100521/solving-a-first-order-pde-system/100561#100561) to solve an exact ODE with 4 independent variables. This works

```
DSolve[D[a[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}] == D[x*y*z, {{x, y, z}}], a[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

but this doesn't

```
DSolve[D[a[w, x, y, z], {{w, x, y, z}}] == D[w*x*y*z, {{w, x, y, z}}], a[w, x, y, z], {w, x, y, z}]
```

Is there a way (similar to the former's?) to get Mathematica to solve the latter equation? Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: The function `dsolvePotentialPDE` in my answer to [Solve a simple system of partial differential equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141716/solve-a-simple-system-of-partial-differential-equations/145983#145983).  (The other answer solves only a special case.)

```
dsolvePotentialPDE[
 D[a[w, x, y, z], {{w, x, y, z}}] == D[w*x*y*z, {{w, x, y, z}}], 
 a[w, x, y, z], {w, x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> (*  a[w, x, y, z] -> w x y z + C[4]  *)
> ```

Some discussion of the limitations of `DSolve`, which still seem valid in V12.1, may be found in my linked answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is awesome! If I could trouble you or someone a little more, how do I do something like

phi[w_, x_, y_, z_]  := 
 dsolvePotentialPDE[
   D[phi1[w, x, y, z], {{w, x, y, z}}] == D[w*x*y*z, {{w, x, y, z}}], 
   phi1[w, x, y, z], {w, x, y, z}][[2]]

to assign to phi[w_,x_,y_,z_] the formula as the output to the solution to the DE, possibly but not necessarily without the constant of integration (I really need to RTFM as some point)?

Comment: Perhaps `phi[w_, x_, y_, z_] = Block[{phi1, w, x, y, z},
  phi1[w, x, y, z] /. 
   dsolvePotentialPDE[
    D[phi1[w, x, y, z], {{w, x, y, z}}] == D[wxy*z, {{w, x, y, z}}], 
    phi1[w, x, y, z], {w, x, y, z}]
  ]`?

Comment: WOW!! You're 100% "The Man"!! FYI, here is the StackExchange post using your answer to answer @JinsongYang "tricked out" (IMHO) questions about "angular" work integrals on SO(3) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137879/differential-forms-and-line-integral-in-rotation-group-so3/3739093#3739093 Thanks again so much, this was awesome; it's great being a mathematician in 2020!